# <RUNTIME ERR> C++ 4.5.3 - GNU , ACM Prob 853 - DVD Subtitles

Tags: c++, runtime, case

working fine for me and when trying to compile it online at [Compile Online](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php)

but when submitting the problem im getting a runtime error

ive tried everything and cant seem to figure out why.
working fine for every single testcase i can think of

link to the problem:
[853 - DVD Subtitles](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/8/853.html)

my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

map<string,vector<int> > A;
map<string,vector<int> > B;

struct SandV
{
    string s;
    string v;
};

bool myAlpha(char c)
{
    if(c=='-')
        return true;
    else if(c>='a'&&c<='z')
        return true;
    else if(c>='A'&&c<='Z')
        return true;

    return false;
}

string GetWord(string &x)
{
    int i = 0;
    for( ; myAlpha(x[i]) || x[i]=='-' ; i++);

    if(i==0) i=1;

    string temp = x.substr(0,i);
    x.erase(0,i);

    string ret = "";
    for(int j=0 ; j<i ; j++)
    {
        ret+=tolower(temp[j]);
    }

    return ret;
}

void addA(string word,int line)
{
    vector<int> x = A[word];
    bool has = false;
    for(int i=0 ; i<x.size() && !has ; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] == line)
            has = true;
    }

    if(!has)
        A[word].push_back(line);
}
void addB(string word,int line)
{
    vector<int> x = B[word];
    bool has = false;
    for(int i=0 ; i<x.size() && !has ; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] == line)
            has = true;
    }

    if(!has)
        B[word].push_back(line);
}
string VtoS(vector<int> x)
{
    string ret = "";
    char temp[512];

    for(int i=0 ; i<x.size() ; i++)
    {
        sprintf(temp,"%d ",x[i]);
        //ret += itoa(x[i],temp,10);
        ret += temp;
        //ret += " ";
    }
    return ret;
}

int SandVcompareV (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp( (*(SandV*)a).v.c_str(),(*(SandV*)b).v.c_str() );
}
int SandVcompareS (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp( (*(SandV*)a).s.c_str(),(*(SandV*)b).s.c_str() );
}

pair<SandV*,int> murge(SandV* x, int size)
{
    pair<SandV*,int> ret;
    ret.first  = new SandV[size];
    ret.second = 0;

    int i=0;
    int end = 0;

    string temp;
    string collection;

    while(i<size)
    {
        temp = x[i].v;

        while(end<size && strcmp( temp.c_str(),x[end].v.c_str() )==0 )
            end++;

        if(end-i > 1)
        {
            qsort(&x[i],end-i,sizeof(SandV),SandVcompareS);
            collection = "";
            for(int j=i ; j<end ; j++)
            {
                if(j!=i)
                    collection += " ";
                collection += x[j].s;
            }

            ret.first[ret.second].s = collection;
            ret.first[ret.second].v = x[i].v;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.first[ret.second].s = x[i].s;
            ret.first[ret.second].v = x[i].v;
        }

        ret.second++;
        i = end;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    //freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);

    int    n;
    int    lines;
    string line;


    cin >> n;
    while(n--)
    {
        A.clear();
        B.clear();

        cin>>lines;
        getline(cin,line);

        // language A
        for(int i=0 ; i<lines ; i++)
        {
            getline(cin,line);
            while(line.empty()==false)
            {
                string x = GetWord(line);
                if(x.size() > 2)
                {
                    addA(x,i);
                }
            }
        }

        // language B
        for(int i=0 ; i<lines ; i++)
        {
            getline(cin,line);
            while(line.empty()==false)
            {
                string x = GetWord(line);
                if(x.size() > 2)
                {
                    addB(x,i);
                }
            }
        }


        //
        // work with A and B
        //


        // empty words mentioned only once
        map<string,vector<int> >::iterator it;
        vector<string> temp;


        it = A.begin();
        while(it != A.end())
        {
            if(it->second.size()<2)
                temp.push_back(it->first);
            it++;
        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<temp.size() ; i++)
            A.erase(temp[i]);

        it = B.begin();
        temp.clear();
        while(it != B.end())
        {
            if(it->second.size()<2)
                temp.push_back(it->first);
            it++;
        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<temp.size() ; i++)
            B.erase(temp[i]);


        SandV SVtemp;
        SandV* AA = new SandV[A.size()];
        SandV* BB = new SandV[B.size()];

        int counter = 0;
        for(it=A.begin() ; it!=A.end() ; it++,counter++)
        {
            SVtemp.s = it->first;
            SVtemp.v = VtoS(it->second);
            AA[counter] = SVtemp;
        }
        qsort(AA,A.size(),sizeof(SandV),SandVcompareV);
        pair<SandV*,int> retA = murge(AA,A.size());


        counter = 0;
        for(it=B.begin() ; it!=B.end() ; it++,counter++)
        {
            SVtemp.s = it->first;
            SVtemp.v = VtoS(it->second);
            BB[counter] = SVtemp;
        }
        qsort(BB,B.size(),sizeof(SandV),SandVcompareV);
        pair<SandV*,int> retB = murge(BB,B.size());

        qsort(retA.first,retA.second,sizeof(SandV),SandVcompareS);

        for(int i=0 ; i<retA.second ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<retA.second ; j++)
            {
                if(strcmp( retA.first[i].v.c_str() , retB.first[j].v.c_str() )==0)
                {
                    cout << retA.first[i].s << "/" << retB.first[j].s << endl;
                }
            }
        }



    }   

    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you using `qsort` to sort an array of non POD type?  Use `std::sort` instead.

Comment: thanks fixed that, now im getting WA.